# Getting count of keywords using tm package in R

Tags: r, text-mining, tm, text-analysis

I'm trying to get a count of the keywords in my corpus using the R "tm" package. This is my code so far:

```
# get the data strings
f<-as.vector(forum[[1]])

# replace +
f<-gsub("+", " ", f ,fixed=TRUE)

# lower case
f<-tolower(f)

# show all strings that contain mobile
mobile<- f[grep("mobile", f, ignore.case = FALSE, perl = FALSE, value = FALSE,
     fixed = FALSE, useBytes = FALSE, invert = FALSE)]
text.corp.mobile <- Corpus(VectorSource(mobile))
text.corp.mobile <- tm_map(text.corp.mobile , removePunctuation) 
text.corp.mobile <- tm_map(text.corp.mobile , removeWords, c(stopwords("english"),"mobile")) 
dtm.mobile <- DocumentTermMatrix(text.corp.mobile)
dtm.mobile 
dtm.mat.mobile <- as.matrix(dtm.mobile)
dtm.mat.mobile
```

This returns a table with binary results of weather a keyword appeared in one of the corpus texts or not. 
Instead of getting the final result in a binary form I would like to get a count for each keyword. For example: 
'car' appeared 5 times
'button' appeared 9 times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

without seeing your actual data, its a bit hard to tell but since you just called `DocumentTermMatrix` I would try something like this:

```
dtm.mat.mobile <- as.matrix(dtm.mobile)
word.freqs <- sort(rowSums(dtm.mat.mobile), decreasing=TRUE)
```

Comment: Well, since it's a DocumentTermMatrix instead of a TermDocumentMatrix, the OP is probably after the column sums. Also, this example converts dtm.mobile to a non-sparse matrix representation, which could be slow and/or impossible for a big corpus.

Comment: @josilber I'd love to post an image which clarifies my question, but unfortunately I don't have enough reputation :(